# How to filter a dataview

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I have a dataview that contains a list of tables. I am reading in a list of values that I then want to apply as a filter to this dataview. The list of values is actually in the form of "table1, table2, table3". So I thought I would be able to use this as a filter on my dataview.

```
SqlOp.CommandText = "select name from dbo.sysobjects where xtype='u'";
SqlOp.ExecuteDataReader();
DataView dv = SqlOp.GetDataAsDataView();
SqlOp.CloseConnection();
```

Returns a list of all the tables in a dataview. Any help on how to filter this dataview?

**Edit:**
Not sure if I was completely clear in what I seek to accomplish. To clarify, I am trying to figure out how/if `.RowFilter` will help me in filtering this dataview. Something like:

```
dv.RowFilter = "name IN (table1, table2, table3)"    // I know this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the `.RowFilter` issue:

```
dv.RowFilter = "name IN ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')    // missing the single quote surrounding table names
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like statement

```
"select name from dbo.sysobjects where xtype like 'u%'"
```

As well use Parameters collection

[More Efficient Way of Adding Parameters to a SqlCommand .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299450/more-efficient-way-of-adding-parameters-to-a-sqlcommand-net)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the Parameters collection is intended to help me out in this situation. However, what I am trying to figure out is how to use the dataview's 'RowFilter'.

Comment: I did make the change to `like 'u%'`

Comment: Parameters collection will help from SQL Injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512174/non-web-sql-injection